"as tall as the building" or "as high as the building"
"The new building will be as tall as the Empire State Building" and "The new building will be as high as the Empire State Building." Which one is correct?

There is also a good answer at What is the difference between the words 'tall' and 'high'. This was closed for lack of research in the question, but Drew's answer, in particular, is balanced. Purists argues for 'tall' in your example; most people are less fussy and use 'high', which won't introduce an ambiguity as pragmatics informs the default sense.

tall person, high building, pretty much.

@Lambie Haven't you seen the Google 2-grams below?

I can't see the logic of closing a question like this. The cited duplicate "a tall price" vs "a high price" is obviously unsuitable, since it's about metaphorical use of these two words - and it's been closed, in favour of what is the difference between the words "tall" and "high"? anyway. But even that has been closed - apparently for lack of "research". I don't say my own answer below is the best, or even particularly good, but so far as I can see it's the only place in any of these 3 pages mentioning usage change over time, which is surely relevant information.

"High building" used to be the form the most frequently used; nowadays it is "tall building", but both might be used in the same text synonymously as regards their use with the word "building".

(Official Gazette of the United States Patent Office - Page 429
United States. Patent Office · 1912)
The fact that those two adjectives are synonymous when used with "building", and therefore that both are correct, can be seen in the very comparison used in the OP. However, in that particular comparison "tall" is used more often.

as tall as the Empire State
as high as the Empire State

It's incorrect to assert that high and tall are synonymous. They are not. For example, a person can only stand six feet tall, never six feet high, and an airplane can only fly six miles high, never six miles tall.  The sun is at its highest point on the summer solstice, never its tallest point. You can camp high in the mountains, but never tall in the mountains. A picture that's two feet tall must always be mounted at least two feet high on the wall, and preferably more; you can't switch these words because they are not synonyms.

@tchrist I agree entirely, but my statement should be taken only in the context of use limited to the word "building"; I thought that would be clear, but perhaps I'd better add this detail.

Suppose you built a cabin on top of Mt. Whitney.  It would probably be the highest mountain cabin in the world, but would it be the tallest?

@Xanne - it probably wouldn't be the highest mountain cabin in the world. Photos suggest that there is a cabin at the Everest North Base Camp, well higher than any mountain in the continental US. What, me, a pedant? How very dare you!

@HighPerformanceMark Let's call a cat a cat! A high cabin can also be a tall cabin (https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Yachts_and_Yacht_Building_being_a_treati/sK9WAAAAcAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22a+high+cabin%22&pg=PA14&printsec=frontcover), and thus, the highest mountain cabin might still be construed as nothing more than the tallest of cabins;  to  cut short to this matter of ambiguity,  the highest altitude mountain cabin will necessarily be that cabin whose elevation is the highest in the world, and by no means necessarily the tallest in the world, as "tall", (1/2)

@HighPerformanceMark it will probably occur to you, is an absolute attribute, which "high" is not. (2/2)

Usage with buildings has changed over time...

I don't know of any "rule of thumb" to decide what else is high or tall, but for any given referent, one or the other is often quite consistently applied. For example, it's nearly always tall trees and high mountains, rarely the other way around.

"high walls" too, rarely "tall walls", but "tall glass" and rarely "high glass".

Generally speaking, height is used to describe the distance from the ground/sea level/sea bed... to the vertical position of something above that reference point - a mountain top, an aeroplane... . Often, 'high' is for things that are wider than their vertical height (high mountains, high wall...).
Tallness describes the distance from the base of a clearly delimited thing - person, tree, building... - to its top (i.e. the reference point is the base of the object itself).  Often, 'tall' is for things that are narrower than their vertical height (people, buildings, trees...).

For buildings, the correct one is 'tall' rather than 'high'. The term "tall" refers to physical vertical size of something. The term "high" refers to elevation above some agreed upon 'surface', such as ground or sea level. Thus to say a building in high more correctly means that it's either built on stilts or the land the building is constructed on has a significant elevation above sea level, like for example, buildings located on mountains. Of course, a building can be both tall and high, like a 5 storey log cabin in the mountains.

This is just duplicates information from other answers.
